# After 'emacs --deamon' I can not see new theme in emacsclient frame. It works from 'emacs M-x server-start'

Tags: emacs, themes, elisp, config, daemon

Minimal config https://www.refheap.com/18816

Scenario 1.

- Run 'emacs' from terminal.
- M-x server-start
- Run 'emacsclient -c' from terminal.
- Effect: Theme applied.

Scenario 2.

- Run 'emacs --daemon' from terminal
- Run 'emacsclient -c'
- Effect: Theme is not applied.

Why is that?

.emacs.d/init.d config:

```
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)

(defun install-pack (p)
"A utility function to help in installing emacs package."
(unless (package-installed-p p) (package-install p)))

(defun install-packs (packs)
"A utility function to help in installing emacs packages."
(unless package-archive-contents
        (package-refresh-contents))
(dolist (p packs) (install-pack p)))

;(load-theme 'tronesque)
(load-theme 'tronesque t)
```

or

```
;(load-theme 'tronesque)
;;(load-theme 'tronesque t)
(custom-set-variables
;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
'(custom-enabled-themes (quote (tronesque)))
'(custom-safe-themes (quote    ("b8f561a188a77e450ab8a060128244c81dea206f15c1152a6899423dd607b327" default))))
 (custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 )
```

Answer (score 20):

For Emacs 24,

```
(if (daemonp)
    (add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions
        (lambda (frame)
            (select-frame frame)
            (load-theme 'tronesque t)))
    (load-theme 'tronesque t))
```

or

```
(if (daemonp)
    (add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions
        (lambda (frame)
            (with-selected-frame frame
                (load-theme 'tronesque t))))
    (load-theme 'tronesque t))
```

should do.

Comment: I had the same problem with `solarized` and this worked. I'm curious why this is necessary though, since other themes work find without this workaround.

Comment: These methods record the theme for all frames. Not only for the new. Is there a way to circumvent that?

Comment: What about calling `(load "mytheme.el")` this doesn't work for me (Emacs 27).

Answer (score 8):

Using all mentioned approaches the theme is being reloaded in vain starting from the second frame creation.

For loading it only one time I did:

```
(if (daemonp)
    (add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions (lambda (frame)
                        (when (eq (length (frame-list)) 2)
                            (progn
                              (select-frame frame)
                              (load-theme 'tronesque)))))
  (load-theme 'tronesque 1))
```

### Update

After some tests in Emacs *24.5.1* with the **distinguished** theme and using emacs as daemon, I have got some issues.

If my first client is a terminal `emacsclient -t` and later I open a window client `emacsclient -c`, the window client loses theme configurations.

Then I came up with this solution:

```
;; theme
(defvar my:theme 'distinguished)
(defvar my:theme-window-loaded nil)
(defvar my:theme-terminal-loaded nil)

(if (daemonp)
    (add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions(lambda (frame)
                       (select-frame frame)
                       (if (window-system frame)
                           (unless my:theme-window-loaded
                             (if my:theme-terminal-loaded
                                 (enable-theme my:theme)
                               (load-theme my:theme t))
                             (setq my:theme-window-loaded t))
                         (unless my:theme-terminal-loaded
                           (if my:theme-window-loaded
                               (enable-theme my:theme)
                             (load-theme my:theme t))
                           (setq my:theme-terminal-loaded t)))))

  (progn
    (load-theme my:theme t)
    (if (display-graphic-p)
        (setq my:theme-window-loaded t)
      (setq my:theme-terminal-loaded t))))
```

It's not so elegant, I know, but **solves** the two problems (**unnecessary reloading** and **lost of config**).

Comment: That's the only answer which works for both terminal and window clients opened simultaneously without loading the theme on each new frame; so I believe it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: How about `(unless (member my:theme custom-known-themes) ...)`?

Comment: This solution does not clash with perpective.el and spoil the faces of org-variable-pitch-setup.

Answer (score 3):

The following extension of the above answer fixed the problem for me with Emacs 24, setting the color-theme via the color-theme call, as shown with the solarized theme.

```
(if (daemonp)
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions
          '(lambda (f)
             (with-selected-frame f
               (when (window-system f) (color-theme-solarized-dark)))))
(color-theme-solarized-dark))
```

HTH

J.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a daemon startup, there was no any frame created when the `load-theme` function was involved. After the startup, you created a new frame by entering `emacsclient -c', nothing happened of course.

So you have to tell emacs to apply the theme after frames are created. The hook `after-make-frame-functions` is made for that:

```
(if (daemonp)
    (add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions
              (lambda (frame)
                (load-theme 'tronesque t)))
    (load-theme 'tronesque t))
```

If it's a daemon startup, load theme after frames are created, otherwise load theme directly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this *shouldn't* be necessary (based on the fact that the zenburn theme I use works just fine with a plain `load-theme` call, when loaded by emacs --daemon). I'll be interested to find out if this fixes the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem on Emacs 24, and this does not fix it for me.