# emacs configuration load theme only partially loads

Tags: emacs, themes, elisp

As the last line in  my .emacs file I have:

```
(load-theme 'manoj-dark)
```

When I start a fresh emacs window, changes like the background color (black) take effect; however, my cursor stays black (and invisible). To fix this, I end up typing <kbd>M-x</kbd>`load-theme` `manoj-dark` anyway. Why isn't the line in my emacs config taking effect?

Comment: There are two optional arguments, have you tried the first one -- i.e., no-confirm?  `(load-theme 'manoj-dark t)`  The doc-string says:  *This function is normally called through Customize when setting 'custom-enabled-themes'.  If used directly in your init file, it should be called with a non-nil NO-CONFIRM argument, or after `custom-safe-themes' has been loaded.*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; no dice, though.

Comment: Do you have a setting somewhere that might conflict -- e.g., `(set-cursor-color "white")`?  You can do a word search of your third-party libraries (for `set-cursor-color`) and any other user configuration files.

Comment: The other thing you can look for is something like this, which could be overriding your theme:  `(custom-set-faces '(cursor ((t (:background "white")))) . . .` and also `(set-face-attribute 'cursor . . .`

Comment: No results in either case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem had to do with using emacsclient (daemon). The key was to use the `'after-make-frame-functions` hook.

```lisp
(if (daemonp)
    (add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions
        (lambda (frame)
            (select-frame frame)
            (load-theme 'manoj-dark t)))
    (load-theme 'manoj-dark t))
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/23668935/1542702

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using `after-init-hook` would allow the theme load to happen after whatever has fiddled around with the caret colour during initialisation?

I've seen problems with package initialisations clashing over such things (smart-mode-line and a colour theme, in my case), and this helped me.

Something like the following, perhaps (note: untested):

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook
          (lambda ()
            (load-theme 'manoj-dark)))
```

At worst case you might be able to use `(run-with-timer ...)` or `(run-with-idle-timer ...)` (again, untested), to arrange for theme load to happen a few seconds after the end of initialisation to simulate your manual workaround. It would be kludgey, though.

Comment: Surprisingly, even the hook doesn't work. I might have to resort to the timers...

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645121/auto-loading-emacs-themes-in-daemon-mode?rq=1